# Highlight Specified Number of Cells Horizontally if Condition Met

Tags: excel

I have a question regarding conditional formatting in Excel.

If “5 / task” is written in cell A1, I would like cells A1:E1 highlighted based on the word “task” appearing. I know that I can use FIND to highlight a single cell, but how would it be possible to highlight the other 4 cells it’s right? I would also like to expand it to everywhere in the sheet, so if “8 / task” is written in cell D10, cells D10:K10 will also be highlighted.

Comment: Yes, I am intending to use it as a calendar of sorts so multiple similar entries are likely to happen.

Comment: Yes, there will be multiple entries per row.

Comment: Final question (hopetfully). Will the highlighted areas overlap? For example, if in `A1` there is `4 / task`, will there ever be a task in `B1`, `C1` or `D1`, or will the next task have to be in `E1` or further right?

Comment: No, it is safe to assume that there will be no overlaps. Thank you for taking your time to think about this.

Comment: See edited answer. I slightly modified my original approach to allow for multiple highlighted areas per row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming no overlap between highlighted areas, and also assuming you have a space between the number and forward slash, you could use CF based on the following rule:

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(MATCH("task",$A1:A1,1)),LEFT(INDEX($A1:A1,,MATCH("task",$A1:A1,1)),FIND(" ",INDEX($A1:A1,,MATCH("task",$A1:A1,1))))+MATCH("task",$A1:A1,1)-COLUMN()>=1,COLUMN()>=MATCH("task",$A1:A1,1))
```

In more detail, there is an outer `AND` with 3 conditions:

1. <s>`ISNUMBER(MATCH("task",$A1:A1,1)`: checks the dynamic range `$A1:A1` for a cell containing `# / task`.</s> *Edit* - not needed within conditional formatting.
2. Easiest to understand broken down into pieces. As an example, assume that the cell `B1` contains `2 / task`.

   - `LEFT(INDEX($A1:A1,,MATCH("task",$A1:A1,1)),FIND(" ",INDEX($A1:A1,,MATCH("task",$A1:A1,1))))`: finds the `# / task` cell in `B1` and extracts text to the left of the first space, returning `2`.
   - `+MATCH("task",$A1:A1,1)`: adds the column number of the cell with `# / task`, i.e. `+ 2 = 4`.
   - `-COLUMN()`: subtracts the current column in question. So for cell `B1`, `4 - 2 = 2`; `C1`, `4 - 3 = 1`; and `D1`, `4 - 4 = 0`, and so on.
   - `>=1`: if the result of the previous step is greater than 1, the cell should be highlighted. So `B1` and `C1` are highlighted, but `D1` is not.
3. `COLUMN()>=MATCH("task",$A1:A1,1)`: assures that highlighting only extends right. If this condition were excluded, `A1` would also be highlighted.

[image]

**EDIT:**

Assuming you'll have different rules for different "tasks" and you need to match the specific text "task", try the following:

```
=AND(LEFT(INDEX($A1:A1,,AGGREGATE(14,6,COLUMN($A1:A1)/ISNUMBER(SEARCH("task",$A1:A1)),1)),FIND(" ",INDEX($A1:A1,,AGGREGATE(14,6,COLUMN($A1:A1)/ISNUMBER(SEARCH("task",$A1:A1)),1))))+AGGREGATE(14,6,COLUMN($A1:A1)/ISNUMBER(SEARCH("task",$A1:A1)),1)-COLUMN()>=1,COLUMN()>=AGGREGATE(14,6,COLUMN($A1:A1)/ISNUMBER(SEARCH("task",$A1:A1)),1))
```

[image]

Another look:

[image]

Comment: I tried using the solution you provided but it appears that the word “task” was not a factor in the highlighting. Using “10 / test” also highlighted 10 cells. I will check the formula carefully against what I typed to be sure.

Comment: See the edit. This has been a fun question. I'll let my subconscious work to see if it can be simplified.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am unable to see the magic at work as the formula is over the 255 (?) character limit.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? Can you share the exact formula you tried? Is there just nothing happening?

Comment: I am using Excel 2016. I tried copying and pasting the formula but nothing got pasted. I noticed there is a character limit when I tried typing everything out and hit a dead end.

Comment: I have finally managed to get the solution to work. It was a problem on my part, as I was editing an old .xls workbook, thus the character limit. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Great! that makes more sense. I enjoyed solving this question, and glad it can help you.

Answer (score -1):

Try following

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Task",$A1))
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: But this doesn't fit the request to fill the corresponding number of cells. For example, `A6:J6` should be filled...